# Is there a way to know how inline css property value was set using developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

i'm having a bad time with a javascript-based layout, so I was wondering if there's a way, using Chrome Dev Tools, to know, for example, which line of JS set my element's width. Is chrome capable of detecting that?

Comment: This doesn't use the dev tools, but you could always try commenting out lines/sections of the javascript you may be suspicious about

Answer (score 2):

Under the Sources tab of the Chrome developer tools you can set the execution to pause on DOM mutation. [Here is the link to the relevant section of the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-mutation-events)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since an inline CSS property change actually modifies your element's "style" attribute, you can as well break on the element's attribute modifications (in the `Elements` panel, right-click an element and choose `Break on... -> Attribute Modifications`).